# Getting data from an API and not from Database

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

Morning, everybody,
I'm an apprentice developer, and I have to develop a REST API with django. So far no problem.
The trick is that I don't have to work from a database, but from a Python API in which I use functions that return the data I have to serialize.
I put this schema here for you to better understand (the one on the right is the one used by my company)
[schema of API/DB/FRONT relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95xKy.jpg)

I have no problem to get datas and return them on endpoint, my problem is when I want to PUT, DELETE request.
My DELETE request works with Postman, but when I trigger it from my forehead in sight, I get a 301 redirection error...
For the other requests, I don't see how I can get the data from my form in my Vue Frontend and then pass it as an argument to the python function in Django which must insert it in the db ...
Thanks in advance for your help
Pixi

Answer (score 0):

301 means the url has moved. An advanced client could perform the same request on the new url.
To see where you are redirected you'll need to look at the response header named `Location`.

This may happen because:

- you forgot the trailing slash in the url and it redirects you to that url
- you are not logged in and the view requires you to do so and it redirects you to the login page